# Python Function Get Different Value When Recall

Tags: python, function, numpy

this my function

```
def linearRegCostFunction(X,y,theta,lamda):
[m,n] = X.shape

#hypothesis
h_theta = X*theta

#CostFunction
J = 1/(2*m)*((h_theta-y).transpose())*(h_theta - y)
JReg = (lamda/(2*m)) * (theta[1:,:].transpose()) * theta[1:,:]
CostFun = J + JReg

#GradientDescent
thetaZero = theta
thetaZero[0] = 0
G = (1/m) * ((h_theta-y).transpose()) * X
JGrad = lamda/m * thetaZero.transpose()
gradientDescent = G + JGrad

return(CostFun,gradientDescent)
```

i call with this:`linearRegCostFunction(biasX,y,theta,lamda)`

then i get:`(matrix([[303.99319222]]), matrix([[-15.30301567, 598.25074417]]))`

when i try to recall:

```
[C,G] = linearRegCostFunction(biasX,y,theta,lamda)
print('CostFunction\n',C)
print('GradientDescent\n',G)
```

then i get different values:

```
CostFunction[[319.79620789]]
GradientDescent[[-16.30301567 603.33617052]]
```

i thought it because has not been defined CostFunction and GradientDescent to be zero in the first line in function. how i can define in my function?

Comment: The values you get looks the same when you compare the two outputs. What is the problem exactly ?

Comment: sorry i have edited the code

Comment: If there are no random elements in your code, or a version difference between the two outputs, calling this method in the console `linearRegCostFunction(biasX,y,theta,lamda)` and assigning the values to the variables `[C,G] = linearRegCostFunction(biasX,y,theta,lamda)` should have the same output. Can you check if anything is randomly assigned that might cause a difference in output ?

Comment: @KoralpCatalsakal there is no random elements. All of variables has values from data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `theta` seems to be a list you have to copy `theta`, before you manipulate `thetaZero`. Note, after `thetaZero = theta`, `theta` and `thetaZero` reference to the same object. This causes that `thetaZero[0] = 0` manipulates `theta`.

```py
thetaZero = theta.copy()
thetaZero[0] = 0
```

If `theta` is a numpy array:

```py
thetaZero = np.copy(theta)
thetaZero[0] = 0
```

Comment: Exactly! I forgot about that 